# SilverStripe3: Multiline comments in template

Tags: templates, comments, multiline, silverstripe

In SilverStripe 3, How can I put multiline comments in template file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

single line comments can be done with `<%-- my comment --%>` (or the html way `<!-- my comment -->` which will be sent to the browser, but hidden not displayed.)

as far as I know, there is no multiline comment in silverstripe templates.
An ugly work around would be `<% if false %>`, like so:

```
<% if false %>
    some
    comment
    text
    here
<% end_if %>
```