# How to make SVG build files from a React app available in a SilverStripe 4 page layout?

Tags: reactjs, silverstripe-4

I have a React application called `react-app` nested in a page in my SilverStripe 4 project. Currently it appears in unusable form with none of the CSS styles working as expected and strange things happening to the SilverStripe layout for that particular page (e.g. an unscrollable banner filling entire page).

This question relates to a previous question I asked which received a great answer from Robbie Averill = ([How to insert (inject?) an existing React app (just a UI without a backend) into a SilverStripe page layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55737585/how-to-insert-inject-an-existing-react-app-just-a-ui-without-a-backend-into)).

When I use the command `npm run build` to generate build files inside the `react-app`, there is a `media` build folder created containing files which are not JavaScript or CSS. How do I bring this `build/static/media` folder from inside `react-app` into my SilverStripe project? I can't use the `Requirements class` (of SilverStripe) as it only deals with JavaScript or CSS files.

The generated build folder paths and files are:

```
build/static/js:

- main.f8fcfe77.js
- main.f8fcfe77.js.map

build/static/css:

- main.417390ae.css
- main.417390ae.css.map

build/static/media:

- bottom_image_height_improved_enlarged.0242eccb.svg
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a5.woff2
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.89889688.svg
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.e18bbf61.ttf
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.f4769f9b.eot
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.fa277232.woff
- ic_cloud_download.0258cc94.svg
- ic_cloud_upload.6bf269d8.svg
- ic_help.bb8f97ab.svg
- ic_local_download.ddb824a7.svg
- ic_menu.7f39fb5c.svg
- ic_new.57667fef.svg
- ic_open.ddb824a7.svg
- ic_print.420fc2c5.svg
- ic_save.3fee4fd0.svg
- logo.d6c538c9.svg
- master_menu_cancel_btn.53591bb8.svg
```

Below shows the CircleAppPageController.php file using the init function and Requirements class to bring in the JavaScript and CSS files from the `react-app` build files. Note: `react-app` is nested inside the SilverStripe project app folder.

```
<?php
namespace SilverStripe\Lessons;

use SilverStripe\View\Requirements;

use PageController;    

class ReactAppPageController extends PageController 
{
    protected function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        // Requiring build files for react-app - Doesn't include media folder files!
        Requirements::javascript('app/react-app/build/static/js/main.f8fcfe77.js');
        Requirements::css('app/react-app/build/static/css/main.417390ae.css');

    }
}
?>
```

Here is where I am wanting the `react-app` to appear in the layout of the ReactAppPage.ss (Note: ReactAppPage.php class extends Page.php class.  The layout for Page.ss includes a simple navbar, header and footer which ReactAppPage.ss will inherit).

```
<% include Banner %>
<!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="main col-sm-8"> 
                        <div>

                            <div id="root">
                                I want the react-app with it's independent CSS stylings to appear here.
                            </div>

                        </div>                  

                    </div>

                    <div class="sidebar gray col-sm-4">
                        <% if $Menu(2) %>
                        <h3>In this section</h3>
                            <ul class="subnav">  
                                <% loop $Menu(2) %>
                                    <li><a class="$LinkingMode" href="$Link">$MenuTitle</a></li>
                                <% end_loop %>
                            </ul>
                        <% end_if %>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END CONTENT -->
```

Things I have tried:

1)  If I only require the JavaScript build files the SilverStripe page layout doesn't break.

```
class ReactAppPageController extends PageController 
{
    protected function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        Requirements::javascript('app/react-app/build/static/js/main.f8fcfe77.js');

    }
}
```

On viewing the ReactAppPage I can see plain text for most of the `react-app` headings (not all). There are unstyled drop-down menus that I can interact with. This confirms that some React aspects are working, but the page is still unusable. Can SilverStripe themes CSS files override the CSS files coming from the `react-app` build files?

2)  By copying the contents of the build/static/media folder inside the `react-app` and moving it to a static/media folder outside of my SilverStripe project, SilverStripe will find and run the files, but this does not change the onscreen result.

i.e. copying folder contents from:

- www/my-silverstripe-project/app/react-app/build/static/media

to a newly created folder:

- www/static/media

Expected Results:

On opening the SilverStripe page with the nested `react-app`, the page retains the correct SilverStripe styling and layout. The `react-app` would appear nested in the layout with correct styling (and working like it does when it runs independently of SilverStripe).

Thank you for your time reading my question. I am new to learning both React and SilverStripe and any responses will be greatly appreciated. My apologies if the question is confusing or badly worded. Thanks again :-).

Comment: Currently researching this: https://forum.silverstripe.org/t/adding-svg-to-the-allowed-files-in-ss4/883. Most of the media files are SVG files so hopefully I can get the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to delete the <% include Banner %> entirely from the page as this was behaving strangely. I couldn't just comment it out with HTML style comments because ReactAppPage.ss is a SilverStripe page and not true HTML.

- I found out why SilverStripe runs commented out keywords. HTML style comments are still sent to the browser. I changed to SilverStripe comments `<%-- --%>`:

  - Research: [SilverStripe3: Multiline comments in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739970/silverstripe3-multiline-comments-in-template)

Now I can see the react-app as expected and working as expected.

Some other weird things happened to the SilverStripe CSS which meant the page was not scrolling like the others. The chrome dev tools in the browser allowed me to identify what the problems were happening on that page and then make adjustments to the code. I was able to reintroduce the banner with close to identical look to the other pages. Not the best solution as had to create a page specific banner with inline styles to override what was broken.

My continued problem is:

- Finding the right place for the files in the media folder within the SilverStripe project (instead of outside the SilverStripe project at www/static/media).

Because I am following the SilverStripe lessons (which carve up a static website into a  SilverStripe project) I am thinking some of these problems might be resolved by continuing the lessons. Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Solution:

1. Configuring a virtual host (Document Root and Directory) to point to www/SS4ProjectName.

2. Manually place a copy of the static/build folder inside the SS4ProjectName/public folder.

Solution bad because:
• Have to manually do/check this every npm build of the React project
• You can’t get rid of the static/build directory of the SVG files (as this is automatically created during npm run build).
• The SVG files can’t be placed in the SS4ProjectName/public/resources as you lose access to Composer generated SymLinks if the virtual host is configured to get the SVG files.

Comment: The ultimate solution I am thinking to the problems of the above hack would be to write a DOS Batch Script to automatically take care of these above actions each build.

Comment: I also made sure I configured the project to allow svg files by following instructions at this link: https://forum.silverstripe.org/t/adding-svg-to-the-allowed-files-in-ss4/883